# Which relational model is better for this example?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

This is relational model for a OOP database, which of this is better?:

Note: -> this operand is used to define a foreign key like (field->table(reference))

1. First

   **

   attribute
       (id:auto, attribute_name)

   ```
   type
   (id:auto, type_name)

   type_attribute
   (id:auto, type_code->type(id), attribute_id->attribute(id), default_value)

   object
   (id:auto, name, object_type->type(id))

   object_property
   (id:auto, object_id->object(id), attribute_id->attribute(id), my_value)
   ```

**

1. Second

   > attribute (id:auto, attribute_name)
   >
   > type (id:auto, type_name)
   >
   > type_attribute (id:auto, type_code->type(id),
   >   attribute_code->attribute(id), default_value)
   >
   > object (id:auto, name, object_type->type(id))
   >
   > object_property (id:auto,  (object_id,
   >   object_type)->object(id,object_type),  (object_type,
   >   attribute_id)->type_attribute(id, attribute_id), my_value)

Really the difference is clearly visible at the object_property table.

In the first model you can define a property using the code and the attribute code, the problem here is that you can define elements that the type doesn't define the attribute for the type of the object. However, this model is most easy to use because for define an object_property you only need two codes like:

```
INSERT INTO object_property(object_code, attribute_code, my_value)
 VALUES (3,4,'myvalue')
```

In the second model you can define a property using more consistent data using the object_code, object_type and the attribute_code. However you need to use three codes and additional query like this:

```
INSERT INTO object_property(object_code, object_type, attribute_code) 
VALUES (3, (select object_type from object where code = 3), 4, 'my_value')
```

Which better?

Comment: Is neither an acceptable answer? Seriously, a relational database is not designed to be Object Oriented. This is going to perform very poorly and be a PITA to code against.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say "relational model"? There is only one relational model:

> we've never changed the axioms for the relational model. We have made
>   a number of changes over the years to the model itself—for example,
>   we've added relational comparisons—but the axioms (which are basically
>   those of classical predicate logic) have remained unchanged ever since
>   Codd's first papers. Moreover, what changes have occurred have all
>   been, in my view, evolutionary, not revolutionary, in nature. Thus, I
>   really do claim there's only one relational model, even though it has
>   evolved over time and will presumably continue to do so.

[SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code By C. J. Date](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=406_pJtiJ6sC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)